# NDK project with clang: linker errors

Tags: android, android-ndk, linker, clang, ld

I have a perfectly working NDK project that uses the latest NDK r10d and GCC 4.9 toolchain. I've decided to try building it with clang instead. I've set `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang` in Application.mk, and also replaced `APP_STL := gnustl_static` with `APP_STL := c++_static`. I didn't make any other adjustments, because upon Googling the matter for a while, I decided I don't need any. I have successfully compiled all the sources, but linking throws a set of 3 errors for every single object file (error message in bold):

> c:/Development/Android_SDK/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld.exe:
>   error: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/native_lib/main.o:1:3:
>   **invalid character**
>
> c:/Development/Android_SDK/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld.exe:
>   error: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/native_lib/main.o:1:3:
>   **syntax error, unexpected $end**
>
> c:/Development/Android_SDK/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld.exe:
>   error: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/native_lib/main.o: **not
>   an object or archive**

This happens in release (`APP_OPTIM := release APP_CFLAGS := -O3`), but **not** in debug (`APP_OPTIM := debug APP_CFLAGS := -O0 -g -gdwarf-2`). With debug build, everything's fine!

Here's my entire Application.mk:

```
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_CFLAGS := -O3 -flto -fwhole-program

APP_STL := c++_static

APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++11 -rdynamic -funwind-tables
APP_CFLAGS   += -Wno-deprecated-declarations -rdynamic -funwind-tables -Wno-deprecated-register

GLOBAL_ARM_MODE := arm
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-15
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
APP_GNUSTL_FORCE_CPP_FEATURES := exceptions rtti
#Position-independent executable
APP_PIE := true

APP_MODULES := native_lib
```

What could be the problem here?
Note that it uses `ld` from GCC 4.8, is that correct?

P. S. This is on Windows x64.

Comment: It looks like you've still got it referencing `gcc` from the errors showing